# I'm looking for a Finder replacement with two panes and bookmarking

Tags: macos, software-rec, finder

I'm looking for a replacement for Finder on OS X. The replacement program should:

- have 2 panes, to make copying/moving files easy
- support bookmarking
- support drag and drop
- be free ($0)

I've tried muCommander, but find the UI a bit clunky, e.g. you can't move one folder into another using drag and drop. Something like xplorer2 (windows only) would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

[**XFolders**](http://www.kai-heitkamp.de/cms_en/main.php?content=1&module=6&SprachID=1&uid=fc984cd575ed8c10ff8d520ad80c1bd3)

[image]

**See also:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers

Comment: I don't know about bookmarking though... There doesn't seem to be much choice. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think PathFinder will suit your needs:
http://www.cocoatech.com/

Comment: He wants freeware only.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was freeware :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a free product but if inexpensive is close enough, I can recommend [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) for tabbed interface, toggle-able dual-pane interface, and drag-and-drop features.  (I personally find toggling hidden files on and off to be a must have feature, as well).  No bookmarking, though.